# A function to style specific words on a given string?

Tags: php

How to style specific words from a given string ?

```
$myString = "foo bar";
```

How to make a function that bold a given word if it is found on the string, than return the string again

```
$formattedString = Bold('foo',$myString);
echo $formattedString ;
```

Expected result :
 **foo** bar

How can i do this ? I need to bold some keyword / phrases in the search resut based on typed user query

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like:

```
function Bold($text, $str) {
    return str_replace($text, "<strong>".$text."</strong>", $str);
}
echo Bold("test", "this is a test");
```

Comment: i don't think this helps for the string "this is a <b>test</b>" or "this is a <strong>test</strong>" as this searches only "test" rather than it's tags

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way is to use `str_replace("foo", "<b>foo</b>", $string)`.

Also `RegExp` can be used to perform the same operation.

**UPDATE:** To have more advanced function for *styling* you can use `RegExp` next way:

```
function bold($text, array $words) {
    return preg_replace('/\b('.implode('|', $words).')\b/i', '<b>$1</b>', $text);
}
```

Using this function you can *style* multiple words at one time by transmitting array of words that should be `bold`ed.

**UPDATE:** Advanced advanced variant of this function will look like this:

```
function bold($text, $tag, array $words) {
    return preg_replace('/\b('.implode('|', $words).')\b/i', '<'.$tag.'>$1</'.$tag.'>', $text);
}
```

This way you can `bold`, `italic`, `strike` your text and even `underline` any set of words by transmitting to `$tag` parameter the name of the tag (*`b` for `<b></b>` for e.g.*)

Comment: @ShikataGaNai, take a look at my solution. It should be what you are looking for (_it works with words, not with characters set like `str_replace()` does_). We are using similar approach in our projects.

Answer (score -1):

By using the str_replace solutions that are posted you will have problems when your word is found as part of another one. For example, in Sudhir's example if $str would be "this is a test with testosteron" (sorry, lack of a better example) the output would be

this is a **test** with **test**osteron

to solve this problem you can use regex because you have the word boundary expression:

```
function bold($string, $word)
{
    return preg_replace('/\b'.$word.'\b/', '<strong>'.$word.'</strong>', $string);
}

echo bold('this is a test with testosteron', 'test');
```

that rule would match your word when it is surrounded by elements that can't be considered parts of words

Comment: i don't think this helps for the string "this is a <b>test</b> with <b>test</b>osteron" or "this is a <strong>test</strong> with <strong>test</strong>osteron" as this searches only "test" rather than it's tags